# Android activity theme changes every time I restart Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I restart Android Studio, the theme of all the activities get changed to either "Theme" or "Light", whereas I want to keep the theme as "AppTheme.NoActionBar".

I have included the line:
**`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`** in my android manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure which theme is defined in you mainifest, in the part where you define your application:

```
<application
    android:name=".ExampleApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    ...
```

This is the theme of your application, if you want a specific theme in your activity, you have to set:

```
android:theme ="@android:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

into your activity tags:

```
<activity
    android:theme ="@android:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    ...
```

Comment: It worked! Somehow, the application tag was missing and an android tag had taken its place in my manifest file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I already did that and i'm still losing my theme when rotating, neither my app theme or activity tag's are being applied (the action bar reappears and the color is different from any declared theme i have in my styles).
Event setting programatically "theme.applyStyle(R.style.DesiredTheme, true)" again when rotating isn't solving the problem...